# How to fix error while building glpk in windows

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, glpk

I am trying to build glpk to use in VS2019 but I got a problem that I cannot solve.
In the file Build_GLPK_with_VC9.bat I changed the directory to the folder which contains the file vcvars64.bat but when I compile I get the following error message:

> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.

Somebody has an idea of how to solve this? I am executing the .bat while while admin mode but the error message persists.

**EDIT**
This is the original .bat file provided by glpk:

```
rem Build GLPK with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2008 and
rem Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows Server 2008

rem NOTE: Make sure that HOME variable specifies correct path.
set HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC"

call %HOME%\bin\vcvars64.bat
copy config_VC9 config.h
%HOME%\bin\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC9 all
%HOME%\bin\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC9 check

pause
```

And this is the same file with the path required:

```
rem Build GLPK with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2008 and
rem Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows Server 2008

rem NOTE: Make sure that HOME variable specifies correct path.
set HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC"

call %HOME%\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat
copy config_VC9 config.h
%HOME%\bin\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC9 all
%HOME%\bin\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC9 check

pause
```

The file Makefile_CV9 contains

```
# Build GLPK with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2008 and
# Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows Server 2008

CFLAGS = /I. /DHAVE_CONFIG_H /nologo /W3 /MT /O2

OBJSET = \
..\src\glpapi01.obj \
..\src\glpapi02.obj \
..\src\glpapi03.obj \
..\src\glpapi04.obj \
..\src\glpapi05.obj \
..\src\glpapi06.obj \
..\src\glpapi07.obj \
..\src\glpapi08.obj \
..\src\glpapi09.obj \
..\src\glpapi10.obj \
..\src\glpapi11.obj \
..\src\glpapi12.obj \
..\src\glpapi13.obj \
..\src\glpapi14.obj \
..\src\glpapi15.obj \
..\src\glpapi16.obj \
..\src\glpapi17.obj \
..\src\glpapi18.obj \
..\src\glpapi19.obj \
..\src\glpavl.obj \
..\src\glpbfd.obj \
..\src\glpbfx.obj \
..\src\glpcpx.obj \
..\src\glpdmp.obj \
..\src\glpdmx.obj \
..\src\glpfhv.obj \
..\src\glpgmp.obj \
..\src\glphbm.obj \
..\src\glpini01.obj \
..\src\glpini02.obj \
..\src\glpios01.obj \
..\src\glpios02.obj \
..\src\glpios03.obj \
..\src\glpios04.obj \
..\src\glpios05.obj \
..\src\glpios06.obj \
..\src\glpios07.obj \
..\src\glpios08.obj \
..\src\glpios09.obj \
..\src\glpipm.obj \
..\src\glpipp01.obj \
..\src\glpipp02.obj \
..\src\glplib01.obj \
..\src\glplib02.obj \
..\src\glplib03.obj \
..\src\glplib04.obj \
..\src\glplib05.obj \
..\src\glplib06.obj \
..\src\glplib07.obj \
..\src\glplib08.obj \
..\src\glplib09.obj \
..\src\glplib10.obj \
..\src\glplib11.obj \
..\src\glplib12.obj \
..\src\glplpf.obj \
..\src\glplpp01.obj \
..\src\glplpp02.obj \
..\src\glplpx01.obj \
..\src\glplpx02.obj \
..\src\glplpx03.obj \
..\src\glplpx04.obj \
..\src\glplpx05.obj \
..\src\glplpx06.obj \
..\src\glplpx07.obj \
..\src\glplpx08.obj \
..\src\glplpx09.obj \
..\src\glpluf.obj \
..\src\glplux.obj \
..\src\glpmat.obj \
..\src\glpmpl01.obj \
..\src\glpmpl02.obj \
..\src\glpmpl03.obj \
..\src\glpmpl04.obj \
..\src\glpmpl05.obj \
..\src\glpmpl06.obj \
..\src\glpmps01.obj \
..\src\glpmps02.obj \
..\src\glpnet01.obj \
..\src\glpnet02.obj \
..\src\glpnet03.obj \
..\src\glpnet04.obj \
..\src\glpnet05.obj \
..\src\glppds.obj \
..\src\glpqmd.obj \
..\src\glprgr.obj \
..\src\glprng01.obj \
..\src\glprng02.obj \
..\src\glpscf.obj \
..\src\glpscg.obj \
..\src\glpscl.obj \
..\src\glpspm.obj \
..\src\glpspx01.obj \
..\src\glpspx02.obj \
..\src\glpsql.obj \
..\src\glpssx01.obj \
..\src\glpssx02.obj \
..\src\glptsp.obj

.c.obj:
        cl.exe $(CFLAGS) /I..\include /Fo$*.obj /c $*.c

all: glpk.lib glpsol.exe

glpk.lib: $(OBJSET)
        lib.exe /out:glpk.lib ..\src\*.obj

glpsol.exe: ..\examples\glpsol.obj glpk.lib
        cl.exe $(CFLAGS) /Feglpsol.exe ..\examples\glpsol.obj glpk.lib

check: glpsol.exe
        .\glpsol.exe --mps ..\examples\plan.mps
```

Comment: It would help to show the changes you made to the batch file. So I need to see what it was and what it is now. but I guess it will boil down to a double quoting problem.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I have edited the question with what you required

Comment: what happens when you open cmd and do `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC"` ?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard it goes exactly to the folder with the path specified

Comment: @GerhardBarnard it did not work

Comment: What paths are in the other script that can clash with script's paths?

Comment: ok, but you initially said you made the change to `Build_GLPK_with_VC9.bat` so which file did you make the change in as in the first edit? which exact directory does `vcvars64.bat` live? and is `nmake` in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\bin"`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard the first edit corresponds to the file Build_GLPK_with_VC9.bat and the vcvars64.bat is in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build and nmake is in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\Hostx64\x64

Comment: ok, so then again `vcvars64.bat` is also called in the script. Making path changes needs to correspond across the board.

Comment: well, you pretty much answered yourself then. Have a look at where nmake is and where the script thinks it is.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard well it worked but now I got the following error message: NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl.exe' : return code '0x1'

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find the exact paths for "vcvars64.bat" and "nmake.exe".
I had the same problem, and this is what worked for me:

```
rem Build GLPK with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2008 and
rem Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows Server 2008

rem NOTE: Make sure that HOME variable specifies correct path.
set HOME="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio"

call %HOME%\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat
copy config_VC9 config.h
%HOME%\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x64\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC9 all
%HOME%\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x64\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC9 check

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, correct installation for MSVC 2022 is, for Build_GLPK_with_VC17

```
rem Build GLPK with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022

rem NOTE: Make sure that HOME variable specifies correct path
set HOME="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx64\x64"
set HOME0="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build"


call %HOME0%\vcvarsall.bat x64
copy config_VC config.h
%HOME%\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC
%HOME%\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC check
rem copy to a numbered version which is needed for the DLL script
copy glpk.lib glpk_5_0.lib
pause
```

and for the DLL part

```
rem Build GLPK DLL with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022

rem NOTE: Make sure that HOME variable specifies correct path
set HOME="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx64\x64"
set HOME0="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build"

call %HOME0%\vcvarsall.bat x64
copy config_VC config.h
%HOME%\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC_DLL
%HOME%\nmake.exe /f Makefile_VC_DLL check

pause
```